# Empty matches for the split function in python re module

Tags: python, regex

I just wondering how '**second** empty string' came up in the result.
could anyone tell me what's happened step by step?

```
>>> re.split(r'\W*', '...words...')
['', '', 'w', 'o', 'r', 'd', 's', '', '']
```

If i'm not wrong, first empty match is because of this sentence from python re module document:

> If it matches at the
> start of the string, the result will start with an empty string. The
> same holds for the end of the string

Comment: See e.g. https://regex101.com/r/fogHTq/1 - the string is split on `...` *and* a zero-length match at the end.

Comment: @jonrsharpe yeap that's correct but my question is why it didn't start with 'one' empty string(because of the quote I mentioned) then 'w' ? what is this second empty string between the first one and the 'w' ?

Comment: Because there's two matches before the `w`, one for `...` and a zero-length match between the ellipsis and the character. So when you split you get: the empty string between the start of the string and the match for the ellipsis; and the empty string between the ellipsis and the zero-length match.

Comment: Adding to @jonrsharpe comments splitting by an empty string will return `['', '.', '.', '.', 'w', 'o', 'r', 'd', 's', '.', '.', '.', '']` an empty string before the `...` which represent the second empty string

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See the [regex demo at regex101](https://regex101.com/r/1z0qrN/1): [image]. It shows where matches occur. Now, recalling that `re.split` splits a string the string with the  match values (here, empty strings, locations in string), you can easily see where the split occurs:

- `...` is found and split occurs => `['', 'words...']`
- The `w` is found, so `\W*` matches the empty space in front of it => `['', '', 'words...']`
- The `o` is found, so `\W*` matches the empty space in front of it => `['', '', 'w', 'o', 'rds...']`
- The `r` is found, so `\W*` matches the empty space in front of it => `['', '', 'w', 'o', 'r', 'ds...']`
- The `d` is found, so `\W*` matches the empty space in front of it => `['', '', 'w', 'o', 'r', 'd', 's...']`
- The `s` is found, so `\W*` matches the empty space in front of it => `['', '', 'w', 'o', 'r', 'd', 's', '...']`
- The `...` is found, so `\W*` matches => `['', '', 'w', 'o', 'r', 'd', 's', '']` (note that the last `''` is not just empty string, it is an empty string with end of string position that is still possible to match)
- The end of string is found, so `\W*` matches this location => `['', '', 'w', 'o', 'r', 'd', 's', '', '']`.